# React Hooks: array not updating/changing in useEffect Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

Here is my code:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
    isLoaded: false,
    data: [], // data here
    isError: false,
  });
  let { isLoaded, data, isError } = state;

...

const [refundItem, setRefundItem] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    const refundedData = data.map((item) => {
      // refundedData not changing here
      return item.paymentId === refundItem ? { ...item, isRefund: true } : item;
    });
    setState({ ...state, data: refundedData });
  }, [refundItem]);
```

`data` is an array of objects. I want to find an element of `data` whose property `paymentId` is `refundItem`, and change that element's `isRefund` property value into `true` (-> originally, all elements' `isRefund` properties are `false`).

The problem is that `refundedData` is **always the same as `data`**.

Sorry I am new to React and Javascript, and thanks for helping me.

edit: OMG I forgot to mention that paymentId and refundItem are both number type. Sorry for mistake

Comment: Your `useEffect` will not trigger if the value for `refundItem` does not change. Can you verify if `refundItem` gets changed?

Comment: Is there a reason your using `useEffect` here?

Comment: @PsyGik okay I will add verification! Thx:)

Comment: @Keith I intented to change 'data' only when refundItem changes, and rerender the page. Plz recommend me any better way 

Answer (score 0):

It seems that useEffect might not be triggered at all due to refundItem not being changed.
Try using debugger to see if useEffect function is triggered or add console log to useEffect and check if it prints anything.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`USE_EFFECT - dataLength: ${data.length} / refundedId: ${refundedItem}`);
    const refundedData = data.map((item) => {
      // refundedData not changing here
      return item.paymentId === refundItem ? { ...item, isRefund: true } : item;
    });
    setState({ ...state, data: refundedData });
  }, [refundItem]);
```

EDIT1:
Looking at Zohaib answer it also got me thinking you have state `refundItem`. From the name I would think it might be a whole object and you need to get id from it `return item.paymentId === refundItem.id ? ...` or just as he said it's you might be comparing two different types and `===` also compares types. Examples:

```
1 === 1(number === number) => true
"1" === 1(string === number) => false
"1" === "1"(string === string) => true
"1" == 1(string == number) => true
```

Also check how are you using `refundItem`. Since it's a state element you need to use `setRefundItem` method and not simple assign since that will prevent React from knowing that there are any changes eg.

```
const updateRefundedItem = (newItem) => {
  refundedItem = newItem.id // <= this is bad
  setRefundedItem(newItem.id) // <= this is good :P
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Possible issue** => refundItem is of type number, while item.paymentId is in string.

If this is the case then the **SOLUTION** is to replace

> ===

with

> ==

and the issue will be resolved

Comment: Thx for reminding me of data type! RefundItem and PaymentId are both numbers. Thx ☺️